# No Scroll + Full Page Gradient (Wordpress Template)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a website I am working on: http://thephelpsorganization.com/

Running on Wordpress and using the standard twenty-seven template. I can't seem to figure out how to make the gradient span the whole page with no scroll so everything is centered. I have everything else positioned as I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
html,
body,
#page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You could do this to vertically and horizontally align the title for all screen sizes.

```
.site-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @theMadKing I have edited my answer. I doubt if its acceptable.